# Symfony 5: How can I prevent an Event Subscriber to fire twice with the Profiler (Web Debug Toolbar) active?

Tags: symfony5

I created a subscriber which executes another class->method, which creates a database entry. I can see that the subscriber fires twice, because the database entries are always entered double. I deactivated the Profiler (the Web Debug Toolbar) and that fixed the issue.

Here my Subscriber:

```php
<?php
namespace App\EventSubscriber;

use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\ResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\RequestEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use App\Repository\UserRepository;

class ExampleSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
        return [
            KernelEvents::RESPONSE => [
                ['onKernelResponsePre', 10],
                ['onKernelResponsePost', -10],
            ],
            RequestEvent::class => 'onKernelRequest',
        ];
    }

    public function __construct(
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        UserRepository $user
    ) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->user   = $user;
    }

    public function onKernelResponsePre(ResponseEvent $event)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public function onKernelResponsePost(ResponseEvent $event)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(RequestEvent $event)
    {
        $db_data = $this->user->findUserByUsername($user_name);

        $write_db_entry = $this->user->writeUserData($db_data['user_id']);
        $this->logger->info('Just checking if this message shows twice. It does not.');
    }
}
```

How can I get the code in "onKernelRequest" to just execute once **and** have the Profiler active? It could be in any event, but should execute before the controller gets called.

Thank you in advance for your help.